# Manage column and row on a table based array of php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I use dompdf to create my pdf document.
My case is, I have to create a table based my two query on database.

The return of those two querys is array both.

First Array have 28 ELEMENT, and the second Array have 27 element. I want to interprated them like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|      FIRST ARRAY          |      SECOND ARRAY         |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  8   |  15  |  22   |  1  |  8   |  15  |  22   |
|  2  |  9   |  16  |  23   |  2  |  9   |  16  |  23   |
|  3  |  10  |  17  |  24   |  3  |  10  |  17  |  24   |
|  4  |  11  |  18  |  25   |  4  |  11  |  18  |  25   |
|  5  |  12  |  19  |  26   |  5  |  12  |  19  |  26   |
|  6  |  13  |  20  |  27   |  6  |  13  |  20  |  27   |
|  7  |  14  |  21  |  28   |  7  |  14  |  21  |       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

But now, with my html and the php code :

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">FIRST ARRAY</td>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">SECOND ARRAY</td>
</tr>

<?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($damage_codes as $row) : ?>
        <?= ($i % 4 == 0) ? "<tr>" : false; ?>
        <?= "<td>[".$row->DAMAGE_ID . "]" . $row->NAMA_DAMAGE . "</td>"; ?>

    <?php 
    $i++;
    endforeach;
    echo "</tr>"
?>

<?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($repair_codes as $row) : ?>
        <?= ($i % 4 == 0) ? "<tr>" : false; ?>
        <?= "<td>[".$row->REPAIR_ID . "]" . $row->NAMA_REPAIR . "</td>"; ?>

    <?php 
    $i++;
    endforeach;
    echo "</tr>"
?>
<tr>
```

And gives me result like this :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------
|      FIRST ARRAY          |      SECOND ARRAY         |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  2   |  3   |  4    |  
|  5  |  6   |  7   |  8    |  
|  9  |  10  |  11  |  12   |  
|  13 |  14  |  15  |  16   |  
|  17 |  18  |  19  |  20   |  
|  21 |  22  |  23  |  24   |  
|  25 |  26  |  27  |  28   |  


---------------------------------------------------------
```

How to get them like I wish, Any help it so appreciated.
Thanks.

**UPDATED**, some wrong type in result of my table. So, I updated my question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

create two tables on td columns

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">FIRST ARRAY</td>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">SECOND ARRAY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
         <table>
             <tr>
              <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($damage_codes as $row) : ?>
        <?= ($i % 4 == 0) ? "</tr><tr>" : ""; ?>
        <?= "<td>[".$row->DAMAGE_ID . "]" . $row->NAMA_DAMAGE . "</td>"; ?>

    <?php 
    $i++;
    endforeach;
?>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </td>

    <td colspan="4" align="center">
         <table>
             <tr>
              <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($repair_codes as $row) : ?>
        <?= ($i % 4 == 0) ? "</tr><tr>" : ""; ?>
        <?= "<td>[".$row->REPAIR_ID . "]" . $row->NAMA_REPAIR . "</td>"; ?>

    <?php 
    $i++;
    endforeach;
?>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```